# Is it possible to test XYFocus on Desktop?

Tags: uwp, xbox

I am making an app for Xbox, that uses XYFocus navigation. Is there a way to test it on desktop?

I expected arrow keys to behave similarly to Xbox controller navigation buttons, but they do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using XYFocus relative properties such as [`XYFocusDown`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Control_XYFocusDown), [`XYFocusLeft`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Control_XYFocusLeft) and so on, which are supported only on the Xbox device family, and only when using a game pad or remote control. In that case, these  XY focus navigation behavior you defined will not take effects on desktop with keyboard.

According to [XY focus navigation and interaction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/designing-for-tv#xy-focus-navigation-and-interaction) section,

> If your app supports proper focus navigation for keyboard, this will translate well to gamepad and remote control. Navigation with the arrow keys is mapped to the D-pad (as well as the left stick on gamepad). Many events and properties are used by both keyboard and gamepad—they both fire KeyDown and KeyUp events.

So that use the XYFocus navigation strategy properties such as [`XYFocusDownNavigationStrategy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement#Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_XYFocusDownNavigationStrategy),[`XYFocusLeftNavigationStrategy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement#Windows_UI_Xaml_UIElement_XYFocusLeftNavigationStrategy),
 to specify which control should receive focus based on the arrow key pressed.These navigation strategies are applicable to keyboard, gamepad, and remote control. More details please reference [Focus navigation with keyboard, gamepad, and accessibility tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/managing-focus-navigation).

Comment: Sad to hear, as XYFocus misbehaves in some cases in my app, but I can not debug it effectively, as build-deploy-debug cycle is much longer with Xbox, then on local machine.